# OSGi for Domain Model changes in REST/SOAP based services

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, osgi

Assume there is an ecommerce system consist of granular RESTfull APIs interconnected to orchestrate and compose a business logic.(Similar to SOA architecture in Amazon , OrderAPI,InventoryAPI,MerchantAPI,ItemAPI...etc)
It is necessary to change the Domain Model objects  in order to implement new features/enhancements with the time.

In order to maintain a high-availability , is it possible to utilize OSGi to update the modifications to the Domain Model while the service is running.  (without any down-town to the service)?

How to handle the case if  caching technologies are used (like Oracle Coherence) to store these Domain objects?

Comment: I hope my answer has helped you... Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you have a look at the Blueprint OSGi specification, which is designed to make it easy to use OSGi's capability to implement dynamic services just like you seem to need.

Don't look at the IBM guide (which comes first if you google for it), check this guide first, which is really easy to follow:

http://www.javabeat.net/2011/11/blueprint-and-service-dynamism-in-osgi/

With Blueprint, you have contexts that are very similar to Spring contexts. When you start a bundle, the Blueprint extender automatically creates the context of your bundle.

Any OSGi bundle may publish a service (which is just a POJO usually). This is the standard way to share a functionality with other bundles. Just make sure the functionality you want to share is declared in one or more common API bundles, so that the actual implementation of the API can be dynamically changed later at any time without down-time.

A simple Blueprint context declaring an exported service may look like this:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
  <!-- Exported service declaration -->
  <service interface="com.package.api.SomeServicePojo" ref="beanId" />

  <bean id="beanId" class="com.package.impl.ServicePojoImpl" />
  <!-- ... lots of beans here -->
</blueprint>
```

Another bundle may import that service like this:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
  <!-- Import service declaration -->
  <reference interface="com.package.api.SomeServicePojo" id="service" />

  <bean id="otherBean" class="com.package.client.ServiceUser">
    <property name="service" ref="service" >
  </bean>
  <!-- ... lots of beans here -->
</blueprint>
```

As you can see, the service is injected into ServiceUser. Notice that the instance actually injected, though, is a proxy! The actual implementation of the service may be swapped at any time, by installing/starting new Blueprint bundles into the running OSGi environment!

Although we are referring to the exported/imported thing as "Services", notice that they can really be anything!!! A String, for example!! So you could, perhaps, change the implementation of your domain model dynamically in this fashion, using an exported Factory for example.

Changing the API **definition** bundle(s), however, requires that you restart your OSGi environment... if you carefully design your API to be flexible, you may be able to still modify some aspects of it by simply swapping the API **implementation** bundles, not the API itself, so that a restart would not be required.

This is also the only way to handle caching issues... if you keep your caches in separate bundles from the ones you expect to swap, things should work just fine... state will not be lost if you don't uninstall the cache-holding bundle... but obviously, if your cache contains Objects which are not compatible with your newly-installed API implementation, no technology in the world will be able to magically handle the differences for you... you can do that yourself, maybe, but in my opinion that would introduce huge complexity for little benefit... just program your cache to be cleared when you make modifications which may break if using the old, cached Objects!